# UIViewController - View events life cycle and registering for KVO / Notifications

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, key-value-observing

I'm wondering if there's any way `-viewWillAppear:` would be called without a matching `-viewDidAppear:`. Ditto for `-viewWillDisappear` and `-viewDidDisappear`.

The root of my question is where to register and unregister for KVO and / or NSNotifications of an object who's change notifications will cause the view controller to update views.

For example, I have a model object that is being processed asynchronously and it's string properties could change. I'd like the view controller to KVO those properties and have any changes reflected by swapping out the text of a label managed by said view controller.

*Where do you register and unregister for notifications and why?*

**EDIT:**

A gotcha I've come across is what to do in cases of application state change (e.g. `-applicationWillResignActive`, `-...didEnterBackground`, etc). These changes don't seem to trigger view controller lifecycle methods. Any best practices here?

Comment: why not override the method that sets the text? do your kvo there for the text and then call super on it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this advice, can you elaborate?

Comment: ok, you want to set the KVO every time you swap or change the text is that correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the standard container view controllers, you will always get will/did messages in pairs. If you have written your own view controller container, you may not, but that would be a bug in the container implementation.

Most of the time, you'll want to set things up and tear things down in the 'will' messages. This gives your view controller the earliest shot at anything it needs to do before it becomes "active" and also shuts down things as early as possible when you no longer need them.

When pushing a view controller in nav stack, it is entirely possible that a notification will occur during the push animation. If you set up the observers in viewDidAppear, you would miss that notification. You want to be listening as soon as possible.

Likewise, I would reckon that viewDidDisappear is too late to remove callbacks. For example, a location manager could be stopped in viewDidDisappear, but another location update could be delivered during the disappearing animation. That probably doesn't hurt much, but depending on the application, something weird could happen like an alert view appearing after you've already left a view controller - which looks like a flicker to the user.

Anything non-view related, as indicated above, occur in the 'will' methods. The choice about will vs did, then, is really about what the user sees. Animations should start in viewDidAppear, otherwise, the user won't see the frames that occur during will/did appear. Data should be moved to views in viewWillAppear, otherwise, a blank view will transition in and the data will only appear after the transition animation completes. Also, it possible that a view frames could be adjusted in between viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear, like in the case of a previous view controller in the stack hiding/showing the navigation bar.

And on a side note, not something I will get into great detail here with, but I'd advocate against KVO for controller interactions that move data from model to view objects. Difficult to test and difficult to trace.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but the reason goes beyond the soft/anecdotal evidence presented. Assuming standard navigation transition (not using custom transition or view controller containers), willAppear/Disappears seem to always be paired. It is not the case that DidAppear/Disappears will be. Using iOS 7 interactive transitions, you can start a transition and then cancel it. This will cause a WillDisppear, WillAppear, DidAppear. If you add an observer on DidAppear and remove on DidDisappear, you now have the controller observing same object twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass your `UILabel` and in your subclass override the setText method:

```
-(void)setText:(NSString *)newText {

    //do your KVO updates here

    [super setText:newText];
}
```

hope this helps

Comment: Is there a benefit to doing this in the view instead of doing it in the view controller? It feels like view-controller responsibility. (I assume you disengage from KVO in ```-dealloc```)

Comment: one advantage this would give is if you are changing the text from multiple places you wouldnt have to worry about updating the KVO in several locations. however, you are correct about it being the controller's responsibility.